# How can I inject second databaseContext for API Configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2

I´m building a WebApi and i have some questions...

I created services for each request, like product, customer, sales, etc.. Each Service inject repositories tables that inherits from a base repository like:

```
public ProductService(IProductRepository productRepository,
                      IProductPriceRepository productPriceRepository,
                      IProductProviderRepository productProviderRepository)
{
}
```

And for example a SaleService requires other services like:

```
public SalesService(IDocumentService documentService,
                    ICustomerService customerService,
                    IProductService productService)
{   
}
```

More or less that´s the architecture of my app.
The question is that I need another database context for API configuration how is the proper way to make this without making injections redundants? Like :

```
public ProductService(IProductRepository productRepository,
                      IProductPriceRepository productPriceRepository,
                      IProductProviderRepository productProviderRepository,
                      ConfigurationApiContextService configurationApicontextService)
{
}
public SalesService(IDocumentService documentService,
                    ICustomerService customerService,
                    IProductService productService,
                    ConfigurationApiContextService configurationApicontextService)
{           
}
```

I´m using IoC Unity.
That´s a proper way to add another dataContext to services? It is posible to make that new dataContext global accesible for the entire app?

If this is a proper way, if later I want to add log4net package for logging the entire application, is there too much injections for service?

Sorry for those question, just started on WebApi ;)

And sorry for bad english too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you use this second db context with current repositories ? or just ConfigurationApiContextService will use this second db context ?

Comment: Just configurationapicontext Will use ti second db context, its Just a data parser between data sended by client and data final stored on the system. The question is if there are some methology to this without repeating injection when for exanple salesservice depend on poductservice.       Thanks for awnser :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor shouldn't have many parameters. But you have 4 parameters, so it's fine. You can use [Aggregate Services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/aggregate-services.html) to combine services (combine if they have logical or psyhical relation).

For example if your customerService and Document services live always together, create an aggreate service for them. If you read [Refactoring to Aggregate Services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) document you will understand more.

But as far as I can see you are doing this already on your product service.

I suggest you to use interface for `ConfigurationApiContextService`. That's way you can test easily and lose coupling with implemantation.

You can't loose coupling with rules(Interfaces) but you can loose coupling with implemantations in Depdency Injection. Additionally, you decide implemantations on top level not in middle or bottom (inversion of control).

So your sales service is coupled with Product service rules (`IProductService`) not with implemantation.